# IE throwing JavaScript TypeError but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, magento, prototypejs

**DESCRIPTION**
On our Magento Shopping Cart when a user clicks the *Add to Basket* button on the Product Details page on any of the Internet Explorer browsers they get a popup in the browser with the following error message:

**Exception : TypeError: Unable to get property 'tagName of undefined or null reference**

At first I though this error was due to an AJAX call but after further investigation in the browser debugger I can see that it is being caused when the JavaScript is trying to modify the DOM nodes/ HTML tags and their attributes.

I set the breakpoints on all sub-tree & attribute modifications on the `#mdl_ajax_confirm` `div`, the call stack is:

```
ajax_cart.js:87
ajax_cart.js:89
ajax_cart.js:91
ajax_cart.js:97
ajax_cart.js:99
ajax_cart.js:104
ajax_cart.js:110
ajax_cart.js:112
ajax_cart.js:113
```

In IE it breaks on `ajax_cart.js:104` and goes to `prototype:1617` to handle the exception.

So the offending piece of code seems to be **ajax_cart.js:104** which is:

```
$$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
  el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
  //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
});
```

In Chrome this returns it returns HTML but in IE it returns the same error in the console as the pop up: **Unable to get property 'tagName' of undefined or null reference**

**QUESTION**

I checked the IE console and the `mini_cart_txt` `var` is there before ajax_cart.js:104 is executed, the issue is I believe coming from `el`?  I'm not sure how to fix it or what exactly is happening with that block of code?

Below is the rest of the code, thanks in advance :)

**CODE**

*ajax_cart.js*

```
var inCart = false;

if (window.location.toString().search('/product_compare/') != -1){
  var win = window.opener;
}
else{
  var win = window;
}

if (window.location.toString().search('/checkout/cart/') != -1){
    inCart = true;
}


function setLocation(url){
    if(!inCart && (/*(url.search('/add') != -1 ) || (url.search('/remove') != -1 ) ||*/ url.search('checkout/cart/add') != -1) ){
        sendcart(url, 'url');
    }else if((url.search('catalog/product_compare') != -1) ){
        sendcompare(url, 'url');
    }
  else{
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
function sendcompare(url, type){
  //alert('test');
   showLoading();
      url = url.replace("catalog/product_compare/add","bestseller/index/compare");
    url += 'isAjax/1/';
    //jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).show();
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
           // jQuery('#ajax_loading'+id).hide();
            if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                alert(data.message);
            }
      else if(data.already!='')
      {
         $('mdl-temp-div').innerHTML = data.already;
                var return_message = data.already;
                $('mdl_ajax_confirm').innerHTML = '<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper"><div class="f-block"><ul class="messages"><li class="notice-msg">'+return_message + '</li></ul></div></div>';
        showConfirm();
      }
      else{
          $('mdl-temp-div').innerHTML = data.message;
                var return_message = data.message;
                $('mdl_ajax_confirm').innerHTML = '<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper"><div class="f-block"><ul class="messages"><li class="success-msg">'+return_message + '</li></ul></div></div>';
        showConfirm();
                if(jQuery('.header-compare').length){
                    jQuery('.header-compare').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
          // Clear All

                }else{
                    if(jQuery('.col-right').length){
                        jQuery('.col-right').prepend(data.sidebar);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function sendcart(url, type){
    showLoading();
    if (type == 'form'){
        url = ($('product_addtocart_form').action).replace('checkout', 'mdlajaxcheckout/index/cart');
        //url = ($('product_addtocart_form').action);
        var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
        url,
        {
            method: 'post',
            postBody: $('product_addtocart_form').serialize(),
            parameters : Form.serialize("product_addtocart_form"),
            onException: function (xhr, e)
            {
                alert('Exception : ' + e);
            },
            onComplete: function (xhr)
            {
                $('mdl-temp-div').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                var return_message = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.mdl_ajax_message').innerHTML;

                var middle_text = '<div class="mdl-cart-bts">'+$('mdl-temp-div').down('.back-ajax-add').innerHTML+'</div>';

                $('mdl_ajax_confirm').innerHTML = '<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper">'+return_message + middle_text + '</div>';

                var link_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_content').innerHTML;

                $$('.top-link-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.innerHTML = link_cart_txt;
                });



                var mini_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_side_ajax').innerHTML;

                $$('.mini-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
                    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
                });

                $$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
                    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
                });


                replaceDelUrls();

                if (ajax_cart_show_popup){
                    showConfirm();
                } else {
                    hideMdlOverlay();
                }

            }

        });



    } else if (type == 'url'){

        url = url.replace('checkout', 'mdlajaxcheckout/index/cart');
        //alert(url);
        var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
        url,
        {
            method: 'post',
            postBody: '',
            onException: function (xhr, e)
            {
                alert('Exception : ' + e);
            },
            onComplete: function (xhr)
            {
                $('mdl-temp-div').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                var return_message = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.mdl_ajax_message').innerHTML;
                var middle_text = '<div class="mdl-cart-bts">'+$('mdl-temp-div').down('.back-ajax-add').innerHTML+'</div>';


                var content_ajax = return_message + middle_text;

                $('mdl_ajax_confirm').innerHTML = '<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper">'+content_ajax + '</div>';

                var link_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_content').innerHTML;

                $$('.top-link-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.innerHTML = link_cart_txt;
                });




                var mini_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_side_ajax').innerHTML;

                //alert(mini_cart_txt);

                $$('.mini-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
                    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
                });

                $$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
                    el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
                    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
                });


                replaceDelUrls();
                if (ajax_cart_show_popup){
                    showConfirm();
                } else {
                    hideMdlOverlay();
                }
            }

        });

    }

}

function replaceDelUrls(){
    //if (!inCart){
        $$('a').each(function(el){
            if(el.href.search('checkout/cart/delete') != -1 && el.href.search('javascript:cartdelete') == -1){
                el.href = 'javascript:cartdelete(\'' + el.href +'\')';
            }
        });
    //}
}

function replaceAddUrls(){
    $$('a').each(function(link){
        if(link.href.search('checkout/cart/add') != -1){
            link.href = 'javascript:setLocation(\''+link.href+'\'); void(0);';
        }
    });
}

function cartdelete(url){

    showLoading();
    url = url.replace('checkout', 'mdlajaxcheckout/index/cartdelete');
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
    url,
    {
        method: 'post',
        postBody: '',
        onException: function (xhr, e)
        {
            alert('Exception : ' + e);
        },
        onComplete: function (xhr)
        {
            $('mdl-temp-div').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            //$('mdl-temp-div').insert(xhr.responseText);

            var cart_content = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_content').innerHTML;

            //alert(cart_content);

            $$('.top-link-cart').each(function (el){
                el.innerHTML = cart_content;
            });



            var process_reload_cart = false;
            var full_cart_content = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.mdl_full_cart_content').innerHTML;
            $$('.cart').each(function (el){
                el.replace(full_cart_content);
                process_reload_cart = true;
            });

            if (!process_reload_cart){
                $$('.checkout-cart-index .col-main').each(function (el){
                    el.replace(full_cart_content);
                    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
                });
            }




            var cart_side = '';
            if ($('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_side_ajax')){
                cart_side = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_side_ajax').innerHTML;
            }


            $$('.mini-cart').each(function (el){
                el.replace(cart_side);
                //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
            });
            $$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
                el.replace(cart_side);
                //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
            });



            replaceDelUrls();

            //$('mdl_ajax_progress').hide();
            hideMdlOverlay();
        }

    });


}

function showMdlOverlay(){
    new Effect.Appear($('mdl-overlay'), { duration: 0.5,  to: 0.8 });
}

function hideMdlOverlay(){
    $('mdl-overlay').hide();
    $('mdl_ajax_progress').hide();
    $('mdl_ajax_confirm').hide();
}


function mdlCenterWindow(element) {
     if($(element) != null) {

          // retrieve required dimensions
            var el = $(element);
            var elDims = el.getDimensions();
            var browserName=navigator.appName;
            if(browserName==="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {

                if(document.documentElement.clientWidth==0) {
                    //IE8 Quirks
                    //alert('In Quirks Mode!');
                    var y=(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().top + (document.body.clientHeight - elDims.height) / 2);
                    var x=(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().left + (document.body.clientWidth - elDims.width) / 2);
                }
                else {
                    var y=(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().top + (document.documentElement.clientHeight - elDims.height) / 2);
                    var x=(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().left + (document.documentElement.clientWidth - elDims.width) / 2);
                }
            }
            else {
                // calculate the center of the page using the browser andelement dimensions
                var y = Math.round(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().top + ((window.innerHeight - $(element).getHeight()))/2);
                var x = Math.round(document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().left + ((window.innerWidth - $(element).getWidth()))/2);
            }
            // set the style of the element so it is centered
            var styles = {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: y + 'px',
                left : x + 'px'
            };
            el.setStyle(styles);




     }
}



function showLoading(){
    showMdlOverlay();
    var progress_box = $('mdl_ajax_progress');
    progress_box.show();
    progress_box.style.width = loadingW + 'px';
    progress_box.style.height = loadingH + 'px';


    $('mdl_ajax_progress').innerHTML = $('mdl-loading-data').innerHTML;
    progress_box.style.position = 'absolute';

    mdlCenterWindow(progress_box);
}


function showConfirm(){
    showMdlOverlay();
    $('mdl_ajax_progress').hide();
    var confirm_box = $('mdl_ajax_confirm');
    confirm_box.show();
    confirm_box.style.width = confirmW + 'px';
    confirm_box.style.height = confirmH + 'px';
    //mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper
    if ($('mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper') && $('mdl-upsell-product-table')){
        //alert($('mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper').getHeight());
        confirm_box.style.height = $('mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper').getHeight() + 'px';
        decorateTable('mdl-upsell-product-table');
    }

    $('mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper').replace('<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper">'+$('mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper').innerHTML);

    confirm_box.style.position = 'absolute';
    mdlCenterWindow(confirm_box);
}

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    replaceDelUrls();
    replaceAddUrls();
    Event.observe($('mdl-overlay'), 'click', hideMdlOverlay);

    var cartInt = setInterval(function(){
        if (typeof productAddToCartForm  != 'undefined'){
            if ($('mdl-overlay')){
                Event.observe($('mdl-overlay'), 'click', hideMdlOverlay);
            }
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(url){
                if(this.validator && this.validator.validate()){
                    sendcart('', 'form');
                    clearInterval(cartInt);
                }

                return false;
            }
        } else {
            clearInterval(cartInt);
        }
    },500);
});
```

When I go through each line of code in the call stack before ajax_cart.js:104 both browsers react the same.

```
87: $('mdl_ajax_confirm').innerHTML = '<div id="mdl_ajax_confirm_wrapper">'+return_message + middle_text + '</div>';
```

RETURNS HTML ON ALL BROWSERS

```
89: var link_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_content').innerHTML;
```

UNDEFINED ON ALL

```
91:$$('.top-link-cart').each(function (el){el.innerHTML = link_cart_txt; });
```

RETURNS [object Array][] ON ALL

```
97: var mini_cart_txt = $('mdl-temp-div').down('.cart_side_ajax').innerHTML;
```

UNDEFINED ON ALL

```
99: $$('.mini-cart').each(function (el){ el.replace(mini_cart_txt); //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });});
```

RETURNS [object Array][] ON ALL

```
104: $$('.block-cart').each(function (el){ el.replace(mini_cart_txt); //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 }); });
```

Unable to get property 'tagName' of undefined or null reference on IE
RETURNS HTML ON ALL CHROME

Comment: You use sometimes $$ instead of $. Has that a special reason? Shouldn't it be only always $? And instead of jQuery you can then also simply use just $.

Comment: @progsource, good point.  It's not my script, it's coming from the Magento Theme we have.  I'll check if using just one $ makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: @progsource when I change the $$ to $, I get a different error `Unable to get property 'each' of undefined or null reference`.  I don't think the $$ is an issue as it works in other parts of the script for IE

Comment: ... I see - you have not only jQuery inside - there is also Prototype JavaScript framework (version 1.7)

Comment: @progsource the $$ is the [Prototype $$() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_dollars_method.htm)

Comment: @progsource, just saw your comment after I posted my last one.  Yes, you are right, it is using Prototype.  I'm not sure if it us using jQuery too as they both use the $ symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after quite a bit of trial and error I found out what the issue was and was able to solve it.

The code was breaking an line 104 of *ajax_cart.js* which had this block of code:

```
$$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
  el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
  //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
});
```

This piece of prototype.js was searching the DOM for the `.block-cart` div to replace it with the HTML set in it's `mini_cart_txt` variable.  It uses the [Prototype $$() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_dollars_method.htm) method to search the DOM and return all elements with the `.block-car`t class, it then [iterates over each](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_array_each.htm) of them and replaces their content with the `mini_cart_txt` variable.

The issue was that our theme's HTML was modified and now included two div's with the `.block-cart` div.

```
<div class="f-right block-cart span5">
    <div class="f-left block-cart header_cart margin-left20">[OMITTED CODE FOR BREVITY]</div>
    <div class="f-right checkout-button">[OMITTED CODE FOR BREVITY]</div>    
</div>
```

Also the HTML in `mini_cart_txt` variable naturally also had two `.block_cart` classes, whereas in the original theme there was only one div with a class of `.block-cart`.

```
<div class="f-right block-cart span5">
    <div class="f-left block-cart header_cart margin-left20">[CODE WITH SUB_TREE CHANGES OMMITED]</div>
    <div class="f-right checkout-button"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">[OMITTED CODE FOR BREVITY]</script>
```

This was what was causing the exception in IE but not in Chrome.  I'm not certain why Chrome skipped past this exception.  Perhaps Chrome replaced the first `.block-cart` div and then did not continue to replace the second `.block-cart` div which was a child of the first one, whereas IE was running into a kind of loop which caused an exception.

Anyway I was able to fix the issue by removing the `block-cart` class name from the the child div of the first block-cart div.

```
<div class="f-right block-cart span5">
    <div class="f-left header_cart margin-left20">[OMITTED CODE FOR BREVITY]</div>
    <div class="f-right checkout-button">[OMITTED CODE FOR BREVITY]</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK here is what your code is doing and why you might be getting an error and how to prevent.

firstly the block of code that is throwing the error

```
//$$ is the Prototype CSS selector, it returns an array of DOM elements that match the 
//CSS selector
//.each() loops through those DOM elements, el is each DOM element
$$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
  //el.replace attempts to replace the original element with the HTML of mini_cart_text
  el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
  //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
});
```

If `mini_cart_txt` does not exist or possibly is invalid HTML the browser might have a problem replacing the elements matching with class `block-cart` with `mini_cart_txt`. Based on the results of line 97 above it looks like its `undefined` so that might be the issue.

Try to wrap the replacement loop in an if statement

```
if(mini_cart_txt != undefined)
{
    $$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
        el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
        //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
    });
}
```

This might solve the error but disable a part of the code, so another troubleshooting option is

```
$$('.block-cart').each(function (el){
    //change the replace method with
    //el.replace(mini_cart_txt);
    //the update method which replaces the content of the element, instead of replacing the element
    el.update(mini_cart_txt);
    //new Effect.Opacity(el, { from: 0, to: 1, duration: 1.5 });
});
```

this might reveal more about the problem and might lead you to a solution

Comment: Num, thanks for your answer, that would have really helped earlier but I found the issue and answered it below.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please check header type will work

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

Comment: @Emimpro, what exactly does this do?  Does it change the rendering engine of IE to chrome??

Comment: the website is using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` currently

Comment: @Empiro,  I tried changing it to header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1') by modifying the HTML `<head> ` with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` but it did not work :(

Comment: @CreedBratton It doesn't change the rendering engine to chrome. There used to be a plugin called [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/about/) for IE which ran a Chrome like engine on top of IE's in order to take advantage of the enhancements in Google's V8 rendering engine and additional feature support. Unfortunately it's no longer supported so I would probably discourage the use of this as it's not a viable solution anymore.